# Java Bitwise "&" on integers

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I have the following:

```
 int a = 10001000;
 int b = 10000000;
```

I want the following output:

```
 (a&b) = 10000000;
```

But my problem is that java converts to binary before using the "&" operation, and I'd really like to be able to use this on integers in the above fashion. Can this be done?

Comment: "bitwise and", as the name suggests, works on bits. You can't make it work on decimal digits. Imagine you would use it to compute the `&` of digit 4 and digit 3. What should the result be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you will need to write the `a` and `b` literals with `0b` to indicate they are binary. Second, you will need to use something like `Integer.toBinaryString(int)` to get the binary result of your bitwise `&`. Like,

```
int a = 0b10001000, b = 0b10000000;
System.out.printf("(a&b) = %s;%n", Integer.toBinaryString(a & b));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
(a&b) = 10000000;
```

Comment: ok, is it possible to turn a string "0b10001000" back into the binary int representation? Also, thanks for answering.

Comment: @Fancypants753 `int` is a 32-bit binary type. What are you asking? How to say `int c = 136;`? *Or*, `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("0b10001000".substring(2), 2));`

Comment: I want something like  Integer.parseInt("0b10001000"); to return int 0b10001000